# Nested models, setting multiple attributes, some same and some different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I have three nested models: A Classroom, which has many Students, and Students have many Assignments. An Assignment has a `name` and `grade`.

How can I, when adding an Assignment, list out all of the Students and have an input box next to each one for entering their separate grades? I also need one input box that will set the same assignment name for all the students. So the Assignment `name` would be the same for everyone, but each would have individual `grade`s set.

I have all the Students listed, but right now they have two input boxes, `name` and `grade`, for each Student. I need just one box for Assignment, and one for each `grade` next to each Student, all in the same form.

I'm using [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for nested forms, BTW. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the students complete the same "assignment," but receive separate "grades," but it sounds like in your schema you have Assignment pulling double-duty as both assignment and grade, which might be a mistake. The fact that you'll have many Assignments with the same `name` is a big clue that your schema isn't ideal. If instead we think of Assignment and Grade as two separate things, nesting becomes more natural:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
  has_many :grades
  has_many :assignments, through: :grades
end

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :assignment

  # attributes: `score`
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, through: :classroom
  belongs_to :classroom

  # attributes: `name`

  accept_nested_attributes_for :grades

  # a method to initialize a Grade for each Student in the associated Classroom
  # (doesn't assign a score or save the Grade yet)
  def build_grades_for_classroom_students
    students.each {|student| grades << student.grades.build }
    grades
  end
end
```

This would correspond to a schema like this:

```
    Student
  .*  |    *
 .    *     \
.   Grade    Classroom
.     *     /
 .    |    *
   Assignment
```

(Where `*` indicates the "many" end of a `has_many` relation e.g. "Student `has_many` Grades," and `. . .` is a `has_many … through` relation.)

This would give you a lot of flexibility for your use case, and allow you to do something like this in AssignmentsController (hopefully it goes without saying, but: this is all untested and won't work if you just copy-and-paste):

```
def new
  @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  @assignment = @classroom.assignments.new
  @assignment.build_grades_for_classroom_students
end

def create
  classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  assignment = classroom.assignments.build(params[:assignment])
  # ...
  assignment.save!
end
```

And in your view, something like this:

```
<%= form_for [@classroom, @assignment] do |f_a| %>
  <%= f_a.label :name %>
  <%= f_a.text_field :name %>

  <%= f_a.fields_for :grades do |f_g| %>
    <%= f_g.label :score do %>
      Grade for <%= f_g.object.student.name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f_g.text_field :score %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f_a.submit %>
<% end %>
```

(Adapting this for the cocoon gem is left to you, since I've never used it.)

That's a lot to digest, I'm sure, but I hope it's helpful.

Comment: thanks for the help! I definitely this is in the right direction. I didn't know about has_many through: before. A few questions. Assignments accepts nested attributes for :grades, but has no association with them except the :through? Is this ok, it threw up an error for me and went away when adding :has_many :grades. Also, having form_for [@classroom, @assignment] throws up error "undefined method `classroom_assignments_path". I have resources for both in my router.

Comment: ok, think I got it working, using "form_for @assignment" now, also added in a hidden field with "student_id" under "f_a.fields_for :grades". Since I had to permit all those params, "assignment = classroom.assignments.build(params[:assignment])" wouldn't work, but "@assignment = @classroom.assignments.new assignment_params" does. Seems to all be working now! I'll go ahead and accept answer as I couldn't find the solution without it.